# UI appears as big space

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

I build a UI by html, css, angularJS.

The UI looks like this:

[image]

Then in body of this html name: Index.html, I cut all body and put it into another html file name: baseView.html like this:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" ng-app="mystore">
        ....this is content...
</body>
```

after change:

Index.html

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" ng-app="mystore">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

In js file, I change it like this:

before:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: "/admin",
                templateUrl: "/SPA/component/home/homeView.html",
                controller: "homeController"
            });
        //default state
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin');
    }
```

after:

```
 function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('base', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: '/SPA/shared/views/baseView.html',
                abstract: true
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: "/admin",
                parent: 'base',
                templateUrl: "/SPA/component/home/homeView.html",
                controller: "homeController"
            });
        //default state
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin');
    }
```

Then I build, but the UI displays like this:

[image]

I don't know what this error is, but the space disable when I F12 to open devtool and appear when I run code again.

All I can see is that the image is not there, so the sidebar has gone up! Set the image element and working src then the space will be gone.

Comment: All I can see is that the image is not there, so the sidebar has gone up! set the image element and working src then the space will be gone